# Post Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, posting

In replying to [Text Alignment Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129392/text-alignment-problem) on SO, [hyperslug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70492/hyperslug) wondered what would happen if a [non-breaking character string was added to a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129392/text-alignment-problem/1129399#1129399). What he discovered is that unlike a code block which wraps things up with scrollbars the non-breaking string overflows the post element div. A modification to the .post-text CSS is warranted to prevent this behavior.

Example of Problem.
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: Does this happen in the title too? Or on the question listings when the first line contains this.

Comment: Stop attacking the Related list! It's only trying to help!

Comment: Reverse duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/bug-report-the-pollyanna-effect

Comment: "@John Rasch Oy! You got your Unicode in my ASCII!" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: It looks fixed on my firefox browser.

Comment: Looks like this is only fixed for `ASCII` / other normal characters. It can still happen in [very extreme cases](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132485/layout-slightly-broken-for-large-strings-in-questions-on-google-chrome)

Comment: Post Overflow is solved now we have comment overflow.  eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: @SandeepBiradar in [his answer Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42662/61654) mentions that when post overflow was fixed he didn't fix comment overflow. Not sure if this was ever fixed in the intervening years.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `word-wrap:break-word` suggestion is a good one.

Works fine on posts, which are fixed width, and that is implemented.

Near as I can tell, there is *no* way to get this to work on comments because they are variable width. That is, the actual comment size depends on whether or not the comment vote UI controls are present (fex, on your own comment, you don't have controls, if you're not logged in there are no controls, etc), and if the comment has say 100 upvotes that's wider still.

edit: because we loop through comments on the fly for rendering anyway, we are now force-inserting <s>a soft hyphen</s> [boring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles#comment-100386) [unicode spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91498/is-there-a-css-problem-on-stackoverflow/91512#91512) every so many characters without a space. So this should be truly fixed now.

Comment: i don't think it'd be that hard to give the comments fixed width. they only vary by about 45 pixels from anonymous+no votes to logged-in+10 to 99 votes. 50px probably would be enough room for 100-999 votes, and beyond that you could do "1k". (do any comments have 1000+ votes yet?) i don't think having a constant 50px left indention on all comments would be that distracting.

Comment: So it's not really [status-completed] then.

Comment: @ether I'm not willing to make comments fixed size at the moment. I thought about checking server side by looping through the string and forcing spaces every (n) characters if there aren't any just to prevent griefing.

Comment: Please do not overdo using pixels to measure things. The sites scale pretty badly as it is :(

Comment: Too bad, somehow Firefox 4 [is ignoring those soft hyphens](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2399/comments-are-not-wrapped-continued-on-other-side-of-page), at least in `<code>` blocks. I guess that's a Firefox issue, but still.

Comment: Same issue for normal, long comments in Firefox, so it's not only ignoring the soft hyphens in `code` fragments. (My previous comment was about comments too, by the way.)

Comment: Can you do this for comments in the moderator dashboard too? See http://i.stack.imgur.com/NJULm.png for instance.

Comment: I'm not testing this, but the spaces aren't inserted in pre blocks, are they?

Comment: @balpha, just to be sure: inserting zero width whitespace [breaks pasting code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133739/bounty-cannot-be-awarded-on-a-locked-answer#comment381018_133739) from comments. (Hence, I liked [the *visible* soft hyphens](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2399/comments-are-not-wrapped-continued-on-other-side-of-page/2403#2403) slightly better.) But I wouldn't know another solution, other than inserting regular whitespace, which at least is visible! Or maybe using `<span style="margin:0"><code>first</code><code>second</code></span>`?)

Comment: @Sonic you can't really re-write history. Even if now things are different, what's written here **is a response to some old bug report**. Do not change it.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard I've done this before several times with no complaint; this is the first complaint I've received regarding this.

Comment: @Sonic it's fine in a FAQ or even support question, but this is just an old bug report. We shouldn't re-write the answers to bug reports, IMO.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the CSS rule:

```
.post-text { overflow: hidden; }
```

Appears to fix it up nicely.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66430/260841...

Answer (score 6):

日本語にもこの表示問題ありますか？タイ語はわかりませんが、日本語では（絵本を除いて）空白があまり無いです。この一行を長くするには「あいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえお」と入力させていただきます。

そして記号の入ってない空白の無い一行：

あいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえお

Japanese doesn't really have the concept of spaces, but is also not picky about wrapping. Japanese text will (and should) usually wrap after the last character that fits on a line, as is illustrated here. There are no spaces in the above text except two empty lines where you see them, so this is being handled correctly (most likely by the browser).

I would imagine Thai and other languages without spaces are handled similarly, **leaving this problem only to languages with spaces**.

Comment: indeed. Letusalllearntolivewithoutspacesinourlanguage. Onlythencanweavoidthewrappingissue, andfunctionaccordingtothegraddesign.

Comment: I just used firebug, too, to put overflow:hidden, overflow:auto, and word-wrap:break-word on your post and it didn't magically start distorting things either. That's not exactly an exhaustive study, but it goes to bolster the point that there's no reason not to address the issue. (No non-English language difficulties would seem to result.)

Answer (score 6):

Please add `word-wrap: break-word;` to comments, questions and answers.

That's all folks. Please don't make me add *another* greasemonkey script for such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Comments have this problem too apparently. See my test above.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that I know of is to insert `<wbr>` tags into the long words. If it was done at punctuation marks like .-_ etc. it shouldn't be too costly.

Answer (score 1):

Whatisanyonetryingtolegitimatelycommunicatewithalongunbrokenstringofsufficientlengthtooverflowtheelement?alsoacodetagdoesn'thavetohavecodeinitsointhelegitimatecaseusethat.

Comment: Maybe someone wants to know how to fix their broken space key.

Comment: It would be an issue with languages without spaces, like Thai.

Comment: Wow Thai has no spaces! interesting...

Comment: Actually Thai does have spaces, used like full stops in english so there will be less of them in a typical text.

Comment: I think you're trying to communicate something but I can't tell because your text flows under the related box.  Very annoying!

Comment: Cut'n'Paste into notepad

Comment: @HollyStyles: Here is an example of a real case where the text overflowed without the user being malicious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296571/what-happens-when-java-compiler-sees-many-string-concatenations-in-one-line/1296580#1296580

Answer (score 1):

### <s>Stack</s> Comment overflow:

[image: before]

This bugged me, so I came up with the following fix:

```
td.comment-text div
{
    display: block !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    width: 624px !important;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: after]

---

**Note:** In the thread where the screenshots are from, I also discussed another CSS fix related to `<kbd>`: http://meta.superuser.com/a/4791/100787