# fix page widening

Tags: bug, abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

Commenters can break the page layout by posting a long, unbroken string. Feels like the 1990s on Slashdot again!

See [How to convert PNG to GIF using javascript or other client-side tech?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263694) for an example.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment that broke the layout of the linked page before I came here and found your bug report.  Shouldn't be hard for the team to reproduce, though.

Answer (score 0):

Reported to the mods. Users should know better.

Would be nice if the system truncated or wrapped these nonsense comments though.

Comment: Most commenting systems I've experienced have already encountered the attack (either deliberate or unintentional) and dealt with it. Someone who wasn't around for the early days of Slashdot trolling might never have actually seen it succeed.