# Bug Report: The Pollyanna Effect

Tags: bug, comments, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

Look at the comments for this question.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41065/this-ad-worked-for-me

'Nuff said?

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.comment-text div').attr('style', 'word-wrap: break-word; width: 650px')
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `word-wrap` did funky things in IE. http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html 
Apparently the "good guy" here is IE, the only one with that (except FF 3.1) http://blog.stchur.com/2007/02/22/emulating-css-word-wrap-for-mozillafirefox/

Comment: comment text is in fact elastic, though -- there may or may not be UI there depending on whether you own the comment, # of upvotes (imagine 1000 upvotes on a comment), etc. And to my knowledge none of the fancy force-word-break things work for elastic layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix:

```
.comments {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[alt text http://koper.wowpanda.net/socomments.PNG](http://koper.wowpanda.net/socomments.PNG)

Comment: Just applied that by Firebug and it didn't work..

Comment: Won't that just hide the horizontal scrollbar in the browser?

Comment: @earlz: it does work for me. Are you sure you applied it to the correct element? @Robert: no it doesn't. It clips the extra text.

Comment: I applied it to the `<div>` containing the comment(inside the `<td>`)

Comment: What happens to word-wrap?

Comment: oh nvm.. yea, applied the actual style rule and it works... except for with me it makes a scrollbar

Comment: @Robert: nothing. All `hidden` does is to hide (clip) the text larger than the width of the element. If the text isn't a single word larger than the width of the element then it inserts a line break without clipping.

Comment: @earlz: that's a rendering bug in Firefox that happens non deterministically when you change `overflow` on the fly. Try again and it won't show it. It will never show it if you put the rule in a .css file

Comment: That might work, but what about for comments like @Robert Harvey's on the same page which didn't wrap either yet wasn't just one long word?

Comment: You should do overflow:auto instead of :hidden. That way the actual content isn't lost, and you can still ... enjoy ... it all.

Comment: Case in point, the article linked to would hide the attribution to Robert Harvey in the comment under the offender if it were just hidden.