# Mac Browsers: Code Suddenly Formatted as Bloc Quotes

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting, webkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackOverflow code snippet horizontal scrolling broken IN CHROME](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43039/stackoverflow-code-snippet-horizontal-scrolling-broken-in-chrome)

I've been posting almost daily to Stackoverflow for 6 months now without a problem. Today, I suddenly find myself unable to post properly formated code. Instead of displaying with a horizontal scroll, code wraps like a blockquote. I've made no system changes, browser upgrades etc between yesterday and today.

I tested it with three different browsers: Fluid 0.9.6 , Safari 4.0.5 (6531.22.7) and Chrome 5.0.307.11 beta (for Mac) for Mac. I'm running MacOS 10.6.2:

Safari 4.0.5 (6531.22.7) test:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) orderedComponents{
    NSSortDescriptor *orderSort=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[ComponentToLabelMO order_Key]
                                                            ascending:YES];
    //------------------------------------------------------^
    NSArray *sorted=[[[self components] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:orderSort]];
    self.orderedComponents=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sorted]; //use self.property= to handle retention
    return orderedComponents;
}
```

Dang, same problem.

More ordinary format

```
- (NSMutableArray *) orderedComponents{
    NSSortDescriptor *orderSort=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[ComponentToLabelMO order_Key] ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sorted=[[[self components] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:orderSort]];
    self.orderedComponents=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sorted]; //use self.property= to handle retention
    return orderedComponents;
}
```

Chrome 5.0.307.11 beta (for Mac)

```
- (NSMutableArray *) orderedComponents{
    NSSortDescriptor *orderSort=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[ComponentToLabelMO order_Key] ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sorted=[[[self components] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:orderSort]];
    self.orderedComponents=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sorted]; //use self.property= to handle retention
    return orderedComponents;
}
```

Same browser:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FirstLevelZeroTVC *flz;
    FirstLevelOneTVC *flo;
    FirstLevelTwo *flt;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:         
            flz=[[FirstLevelZeroTVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            [self.appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:flz animated:self.shouldShowAnimation];
            break;
        case 1:
            flo=[[FirstLevelOneTVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            [self.appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:flo animated:self.shouldShowAnimation];
            break;
        case 2:
            flt=[[FirstLevelTwo alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            [self.appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:flt animated:self.shouldShowAnimation];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

[Here's a screenshot of what I see.](http://yfrog.com/joscreenshot20100320at436p)

What I'm seeing might be similar that [reported in this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43039/stackoverflow-code-snippet-horizontal-scrolling-broken-in-chrome/43078#43078)

Anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: I moved the code blocks to meta

Comment: @rep dēpō: I don't know if it was on purpose, but with your current name we can't access to your profile unless we remove the display name part.

Comment: @voyager: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43051/user-profile-page-url-is-incorrect -- it was absolutely intentional on Kyle's part.

Comment: I hijacked the stackoverflow answer because I wasn't sure that the error would transfer.

Comment: Already reported in  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43039/stackoverflow-code-snippet-horizontal-scrolling-broken-in-chrome/43089#43089

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behavior on Chrome in Linux.

Firefox formats the code blocks correctly, which gives me the impression that it must be a Webkit related problem.

Comment: Did the behavior you see start suddenly?

Comment: I just noticed it now, @tec.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue on Chrome 4.1.249.1036 stable and IE8 8.0.7600.16385 (32 and 64bit) running on Windows 7 64 bit. Firefox 3.6 does the right thing.