# comments overlapping and widening page

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

[So you guys solve this problem with word wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/who-has-solved-the-long-word-breaks-my-div-problem-hint-not-stackoverflow/320467#320467). However I notice in the comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739948/in-sql-mysql-are-there-reasons-not-to-put-one-to-one-relationship-in-the-same/2739970#2739970) the text makes the page go wider and overlap the related column. Using Firefox 3.6.3/windows7

Comment: (replicate('A',5000),replicate('B',5000),replicate('C',5000),replicate('D',5000),replicate('E',5000),replicate('F',5000),replicate('G',5000),replicate('H',10000))

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to fix with variable width `<div>` which is what we have in comments. (size depends on how many votes, whether you have flag/vote controls, etc)

And no, I don't want to make them fixed width.