# StackOverflow Site Layout Problem in Chrome

Tags: support, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

I was cleaning up one of my questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947336/javascript-rich-display-wysiwyg-component-methodology/2954972#2954972) and noticed that Stack Overflow's comments were overflowing into the right column in Chrome. The question is, what's the difference in CSS handling between Chrome and Firefox.  I don't have access to Safari, Opera, et al.  Can someone tell me in which browsers the error manifests?  Is it just me?

Here's the layout error:
[alt text http://scorebored.net/temp/stackOVerflowerror.png](http://scorebored.net/temp/stackOVerflowerror.png)
*(my apologies to Tim Down for covering up his name with my comment bubble)*

Since I have no natural skill for good layouts and the whole process makes me sad, I wonder if someone can diagnose the error on StackOverflow and make a recommendation on how to avoid it.  Is this a consequence of embedding a **div** inside a **td**?

Comment: that's a curious problem indeed. i have a similarly long answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948749/how-does-your-team-handle-support-requests here but im not getting the same error as you did. (and yeah i can reproduce your bug in chrome)

Comment: Looks like the problem is related to that long URL: Firefox is breaking it on a "/" whereas Chrome doesn't want to break it.

Comment: oh yeah didn't see that one. yup it's the long url then.

Comment: See also [this issue here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132485/layout-slightly-broken-for-large-strings-in-questions-on-google-chrome)