# Layout slightly broken for large strings in questions on Google Chrome

Tags: bug, design

Here's how [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580992/how-to-get-text-value-from-oracle-blob) (corrected in the mean-time, so check the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10580992/1)) renders in Google Chrome (18.0.1025.168 m). The text isn't wrapped (or hidden) correctly:

[image: bad rendering in Chrome]

And here's the same question in Firefox (12.0). The text seems to be wrapped:

[image: better rendering in Firefox]

I didn't check if this also happens for "more sensible" text. It seems to have been fixed before for weird blocks of text, as can be seen here:

[Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

Maybe the above fix just doesn't work with crazy unicode characters... Anyway, I guess it's a rather minor thing...

Comment: K, well I added a line break to fix it now, but yes... it is (was) broken :P

Comment: @Matt: Yeah I've mentioned your correction now. Thanks for giving me more work! :)

Comment: @Lukas.... just what you wanted on a Monday morning, I'm sure ;).

Comment: Should we just add a disclaimer? "Warning: posting crazy may result in crazy."

Comment: See also [this similar question here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)