# Please help me eliminate stem/dangling tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-block-request, clean-up

There are currently a few year tags that should be removed (unless the year or number itself is an issue), probably added because of versioning.

Years:

- [2002](/questions/tagged/2002) -> Done by jjnguy
- [2005](/questions/tagged/2005) -> Done by KennyTM
- [2007](/questions/tagged/2007) -> Boom, no more!
- [2008](/questions/tagged/2008) -> Has popped up at least once on 2012-01-20
- [2009](/questions/tagged/2009) -> Done by jjnguy
- [2010](/questions/tagged/2010) -> Done (and done again 07/21/2011, it came back...)

Dangling version:

- [2.0](/questions/tagged/2.0) -> Done
- [3.5](/questions/tagged/3.5) -> Done
- [4](/questions/tagged/4) -> Done
- [4.0](/questions/tagged/4.0) -> Done
- [6.8](/questions/tagged/6.8) -> Done by KennyTM
- [9.0](/questions/tagged/9.0) -> Done by jjnguy
- [sp2](/questions/tagged/sp2) -> Done
- [sp3](/questions/tagged/sp3) -> Done
- [express](/questions/tagged/express) -> Now a valid concept (node.js feature). Curses!!
- [express-edition](/questions/tagged/express-edition) -> Eliminated
- [lite](/questions/tagged/lite) -> Done
- [xp](/questions/tagged/xp) -> Done - synonym
- [crystal](/questions/tagged/crystal) (As in Crystal Reports) -> synonym

Many of these are just `[product]-[year]` without the hyphen or `[product][year]`. In the 2010 category, Visual Studio 2010 and Sharepoint 2010 seem prevalent.

Ultimately, can we add a ban on these tags?

SUPPLEMENTAL:

Other dangling tags (be careful, as some may be genuinely intended):

- Visual Studio: [visual+studio](/questions/tagged/visual%2bstudio) -­­­­­­­­> Done, studio tag eliminated manually, [blacklist request made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115306/please-blacklist-the-studio-tag).
- Visual Basic : [visual+basic](/questions/tagged/visual%2bbasic) -> Done
- Visual C : [visual+c](/questions/tagged/visual%2bc) -> Done (remaining are genuine)
- Visual C++ : [visual+c++](/questions/tagged/visual%2bc%2b%2b) -> Done
- vb.net : [vb+.net](/questions/tagged/vb%2b.net) -> Refused (too many!)
- Objective-C : [objective+c](/questions/tagged/objective%2bc) -> Done
- iPhone-sdk: [iphone+sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone%2bsdk) -> Refused (over 1500 of these..)
- iPad-sdk: [ipad+sdk](/questions/tagged/ipad%2bsdk)
- iPhone-sdk AND iPad-sdk [iphone+ipad+sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone%2bipad%2bsdk)
- Core-Data: [core+data](/questions/tagged/core%2bdata) -­> Done
- cocoa-touch: [cocoa+touch](/questions/tagged/cocoa%2btouch)
- google-apps: [google+apps](/questions/tagged/google%2bapps)
- google-app-engine: [google+app+engine](/questions/tagged/google%2bapp%2bengine) and [google+apps+engine](/questions/tagged/google%2bapps%2bengine) -> Done
- node and node.js: [node+node.js](/questions/tagged/node%2bnode.js) -> Done
- my and sql: [my+sql](/questions/tagged/my%2bsql) -> Done
- unit-testing: [unit+testing](/questions/tagged/unit%2btesting) - Done (separate blacklist request on [unit](/questions/tagged/unit)  [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115017/please-blacklist-the-unit-tag))

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59557/ban-numeric-only-tags), and specifically [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59557/ban-numeric-only-tags/59614#59614).

Comment: It seems that some of the [2007] and [2003] tags are for Office product questions that have been moved, and can't be retagged.

Comment: @YiJiang: I went through and deleted any that were closed and couldn't be retagged.

Comment: Retagged a bunch...but then I got bored...

Comment: @jinguy: That's why I made this question. Same case here, plus I hit a wall in some cases. Is there such as thing as C#-2010? Should there be?

Comment: I retagged a bunch from the later years, but don't know enough about some of the products to be comfortable doing them all.

Comment: @Mpel, nope, that is not a thing.

Comment: ...And then I got even more bored at work, and went back to tagging...

Comment: @jjnguy: I see your OCD is stronger than mine.

Comment: @MPelletier Its `jjnguy` *giggle* This almost feels like an inside joke now

Comment: Are you just all removing the tag or re-tagging? For example, if there's tags "visual studio 2010" (as I saw numerous times), do you just remove 2010 or hyphen it all to something usable?

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Great, now my damn eyes need to be checked. (I really thought `jinguy` was catchy).

Comment: I changed `visual 2010 studio` to `visual-studio-2010`  I made sure it had the sponsor logo on it.

Comment: @YiJi Thanks for pointing that out.  I have just learned to live with mis spellings of my name.

Comment: People 'pronounce' it `jinguy` which is ok.  Otherwise I have no idea how to say it.  (but I like to keep it `jjnguy` because those are my initials (jjn))

Comment: 88 questions marked 2.0.. needs cleaning up

Comment: 2.0 is down to 55.. this is exhausting and slow.

Comment: retagged all [2007] but 2 that are closed... and still bored :-)

Comment: @Carlos, I flagged them  They should be cleaned up by moderators soon.

Comment: @Change, it is an arduous process, way too much work.

Comment: Just cleared the last two [2007]s.

Comment: @mmy, thanks for taking care of it.  I feel like a mod flag is kinda like the bat symbol...

Comment: @jjnguy: Be nice if there was a mass query. Some of the 2.0 map nicely to .net-2.0 but others don't such as why a tag ruby and 2.0 would be on the same question. I don't know Ruby so it made sense to just delete it altogether since the 2.0 tag is useless in any case.

Comment: 2.0 is done! On to others...

Comment: working on 3.5 - could use some help (80 to go) :)

Comment: @Changeling, I'm done with 4.0, I'll lend you a hand with 3.5

Comment: did a few 3.5's.  Have fun...

Comment: @KennyTM: Good finds!

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble deciphering the iphone-sdk, ipad-sdk, et al. Plus Cocoa-Touch, of which I know very little.

Comment: Tag 4.0 recleared.

Comment: @Anthony Now that it has a wiki, I wonder if it will remain available for users to pick. Tags usually die if they go unused after a short while.

Comment: Added unit+testing to the list, as I've just eliminated [unit] and don't want it to sneak back again.

Answer (score 6):

In addition, I found the following:

```
7bit       5 tags
8bit       8 tags
16bit     26 tags 
24-bit     8 tags
32bit    209 tags
64bit    887 tags
128-bit    7 tags
```

I think it should be either xxbit or xx-bit and based on the numbers, changing 24-bit to 24bit and 128-bit to 128bit looks like the most valid option. Only 15 to change. Unless there is a very good reason to leave it this way.

Comment: ok, I fixed the 24-bit and 128-bit ones.