# "You have already raised this flag" Well, not really

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, flag-dialog

After I [joined the mob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188815/whos-supposed-to-stop-spam-on-the-bitcoin-se-site) and flagged some spam on the [Bitcoin Beta](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/), for a poorly-understood reason, I went back to one of the questions I'd flagged and opened the flag dialog. There, I saw something of little importance, but of less than perfect... perfection:

> [image]

I had flagged [the (now deleted) question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12096/spam-spam-spam-spam-spam-spam-spam-spam-spam-spam) as spam. I had *not* flagged the question as "not welcome in our community". And, for what it's worth, I had not added a custom flag, so... that part's right.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe this has to do with the fact that both of these are red flags; I wonder if they both count toward the same deletion threshold? Meaning three spam and three offensive would cause auto deletion just as six spam xor six offensive would.

Comment: The flags are stored separately internally, but I believe they count towards the same threshhold.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: .. six spam xor six offensive => six spam ⊕ six offensive ?

Comment: Any update on this? With the very recent flag changes this is very obvious to me now.

Comment: The dupe has a good answer, even though it is a later one...