# Raising a moderator attention flag in addition to a spam/offensive flag

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags, user-interface, spam

If I flag a post as offensive or spam, the UI tells me that I can raise an other (needs ♦ moderator attention) flag. I can type a message:

[image: flagging dialog screenshot]

But after submitting the flag, I get a pop-up telling me that I've “already flagged this post for moderator attention”.

[image: popup screenshot]

And the flag is indeed not submitted.

What's wrong:

- According to the terminology used by the flagging dialog, I have not flagged the post for moderator attention, I've only cast a different type of flag (spam or offensive).
- The UI should not goad me into typing a flag and then reject it.

If I can't cast both a spam/offensive and custom flag on a post, then the message in the flagging dialog should change from “you have already raised this type of flag” to “you have already flagged this post”, and should not let me type a flag that by all appearances is a different type.

I think it does make sense to allow casting both a spam/offensive flag and a custom flag: the spam/offensive flag to get the offending content out of the way as fast as possible, and the custom flag to provide moderators with additional contextual information (e.g. that a particular post that would appear borderline out of context is clearly spam that's been hitting other sites). So my question is both a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) about the inconsistent UI, and a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to fix that by treating spam/offensive and custom flags as different types (which IIRC used to be the case) rather than by changing the UI.

<sub>N.B. This is different from ["You have already raised this flag" Well, not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188818/you-have-already-raised-this-flag-well-not-really), which is about spam and offensive being considered the same type. *That* makes sense and is handled consistently.</sub>

Comment: Partial dupe (part 2, UI should not goad): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184809/if-i-cant-flag-a-post-dont-wait-until-after-ive-typed-an-explanation-to-tell .  Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212784/when-flagging-could-we-see-any-previous-flags-weve-raised-on-the-same-post