# 125 rep privileges description still mentions review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, privileges

I just noticed on the main site that I lost review privileges, and after a bit of confusion, noticed that it was because the rep required was brought up to 500, which I lack.

However, I noticed [the description of the privileges description for 125 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) still mentions gaining access to the review queue, which is now inaccurate. This should probably be fixed.

Comment: Not sure if this should be considered a separate issue, but I still have access to the review page, just not access to any individual queue. Just a page of grayed out links

Comment: You don't even need to be logged in to *access* /review - that's by-design.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked that on this site. However, it might be best not to show the link before I can use it.

Comment: Yeah, good point.

Comment: On a related note, why was the rep minimum brought up? Just wondering.

Comment: @Gaelan Because we needed something to give to people when they reach 500 rep (or at least, someone *thought* we needed something for this). It was semi-arbitrarily decided that the review queue would be a good gift. More information [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark).

Comment: @Cody Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @CodyGray I must say I agree with this change. I was reviewing with 200+ and I was going to write to propose an increase on the minimum. Users must be prepared enough to review Q&A in my opinion. Thumbs up for the decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've edited the privilege page for 125 reputation to remove the mention of Review; it will take a little while to propagate to all sites, but the change should be live everywhere soon.

Comment: How long is it likely to take to propagate?

Comment: And I see that it's now live on SO