# I can't review posts anymore—was the minimum reputation changed?

Tags: support, review, privileges

Is it just for me, or has the privilege to review new posts and late answers changed for everyone?

I recently started being more active in reviewing, but the rep requirement just shot up and I can not review anymore? The rep requirement has shot up to 500. Is this just for me, as a 'process", or has it been changed site wide?

Comment: It appears to have been site wide. It is listed on the priveleges page as 500 rep for me too.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Just when I was picking up speed :-)

Comment: Note that you can still participate in improving the site, even if you can't access the specialized queue, and are very much encouraged to do so! You'll just have to do it as you come across the questions and answers "organically". And a hint: questions with recent activity will often appear on the front page.

Comment: @gnat There's no way this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @AnnaLear have you seen the answers, here and there? "The reputation requirement to access the First Posts and Late Answers queue was just bumped up to [fill the empty 500 reputation privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark)."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reputation requirement to access the First Posts and Late Answers queue was just bumped up to [fill the empty 500 reputation privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark).