# Why am I unable to review First Posts and Late Answers?

Tags: support, reputation, review, privileges

Why am I unable to review First Posts and Late Answers? Am I now prohibited from reviewing posts? Or is it some technical error?

Answer (score 2):

Your [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107115/freakyuser?tab=reputation) is below 500. You need reputation  to [review first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), this has [increased to 500](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190549/223277).

Comment: His reputation was never above 500...

Comment: @animuson yep saw that.. see my edit explanation

Comment: I see no evidence of this. Ignoring possible deleted content, Freak's rep before their bounty on June 24 would have been 484.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta yes sorry my bad.. let me get some links and improve my answer.. my fault for jumping in half cocked so to speak

Comment: em still editing to salvage a bad answer.. I try not to delete posts, I try to salvage.. brb

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta done.. sorry, I should've investigated this more thoroughly before jumping in with a dup answer to a dup question, but I think this suffices as a suitable resource, pls advise

Comment: @Skippy, eh, no worries, I'd say leave the answer here.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta that is two new features I have jumped in to ask or answer and not known about... I think I need to improve my Meta studies :) what was the min rep to review posts, I always forget the numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges is a handy resource I use frequently. Such a `/privileges` page exists for all sites.

Comment: @CodyGray yeh I use that all the time, but it's not showing the defunct rep levels.. I was looking for a post on meta that had a list of old rep levels. I am actually surprised it was lower than 500

Comment: It was 125 - or the threshold for down-voting - before this change. It was 125 because we didn't have a good reason *not* to make it 125, but in hindsight this was a wasted opportunity to give folks something new at a slightly higher rep-level.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190808/187824

Comment: @hims056 ty beautiful..

Comment: @Shog9 ty for that.. I actually find all this interesting (I have no idea WHY) There is a lot to learn coming here and trying to be a useful participant.. I reckon it's easier to study a law degree ;))