# Link to review on post is gone

Tags: support, review, new-users, late-answers

Quite few months ago I used to review first-posts and late answer post through review link on Stack Overflow.
But now the review link is gone.
Is there any reason why the review link is gone?

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 3):

[The privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) to review First Posts and Late Answers [has been changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186373/187824) from 125 to 500, so you need to earn 500 reputation to get back that privilege.

Comment: Amen to the Last :-)

Comment: @kleopatra - I didn't get you ??

Comment: jokes on Monday morning might go wrong .. sorry: there's a (Freudian, maybe :-) typo in your  _late answers_

Comment: @kleopatra - Ohh got it. thanks. Monday blues.