# review option missing on desktop?

Tags: support, review

is it just for me or is the review option missing from stack overflow? Has it been removed or is it a real bug because i searched everywhere but i couldn't find the review option anymore.!
I used to edit and review "first posts" and "Late Answers".
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need atleast 500 reputations to review first posts and late answers.

It is due to the [privilage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark) request for 500 rep which came on effect from a few days before..

Comment: Ya, i guess the minimum rep was revised. I only found that out just now.