# Chatting to users with limited rep

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

**Update**

This question has been closed on the grounds that it is a *"duplicate"* that *"already has an answer"*. However the indicated duplicate is another post from two years ago, has no *accepted* answer, and the single solution it received is a convoluted process that is effective only for *diamond-level moderators*. I am not one of those, and few people are.

This issue has been hanging around for far too long without an explanation or a resolution. Accordingly this question *should be reopened*.

---

I have been helping a rep 13 user at length in the comments section, and got the automatic prompt to take the discussion to a chat room. Of course I was unable to do this.

The way it seems to me that it should work is that someone of sufficient reputation can invite *anyone* to a chat room. If not, then *please* can we silence the prompt telling me to do it!

A similar question has been asked before, but that was a *why is it this way* rather than a *can we fix it like this*.

---

Searching a little more carefully, it seems that this has been raised before [here](/q/97876), and [here](/q/100291). The gist of the explanation is that the chat server is separate from the main servers, and in the general case it requires an HTTP request to determine a user's chat reputation.

However, this was raised in July 2011 and the questions gained 58 and 82 upvotes respectively. It seems that this feature is highly desirable and I am surprised there has been no movement in 28 months.

Comment: +1 for "Level 13 user"

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: Huh? Are you congratulating me for mingling with the plebeians?!

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186384/162102

Comment: @Borodin, no "level 13" makes it sounds like SO is an MMORPG. It would be better to say "a user with 13 rep points".

Comment: also +1 for "Level 13 user"

Comment: +1 because this makes sense

Comment: Unfortunately, this should probably remain closed. While the other question is old, the circumstances surrounding this issue have not changed, so the old question is still entirely valid. As this does not add anything new to the old post, I am voting to leave this closed.

Comment: @Emracool: I suggest that it would make more sense to close the older post, since it has fallen into neglect. The problem is still unsolved, and the presence of the other question has clearly done nothing in two years to make any difference. And, thankfully, you can't vote to leave a qestion closed.

Comment: @Borodin You can do so from the review queues :] And perhaps that is the case, yes... I'm ambivalent in that case.