# What is the history of changes in Stack Overflow's privilege policies?

Tags: discussion, privileges, stack-exchange-history

We can access current privilege policies from https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. However, changes to the policies are not documented there. There has been at least one notable change - [the requirement to access review queues was increased from 125 to 500 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186538/223030). How can historical data on privileges be accessed?

Comment: `the privileges for review has been transfer from 125 reputation to minimum 500 reputation.`  This is the first change that I am aware of.  Most other "changes" revolve around adding new privileges and not changing existing privileges.

Comment: Closest thing is probably http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privileges

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Internet Archive to the rescue!

- For 2008-09-16 to 2010-11-10, refer to [/faq](http://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/https://stackoverflow.com/faq).
- For 2010-11-11 to 2013-06-30, refer to [/privileges](http://web.archive.org/web/20101011123402/https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).
- For 2013-07-01 to *(present)*, refer to [/help/privileges](http://web.archive.org/web/20130701032659/https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

(Note that "access review queues" wasn't a concrete privilege for a long time, and [/review](http://web.archive.org/web/20120930143447/https://stackoverflow.com/review) doesn't give much indication when you're not logged in (the Archive-bot isn't) - you'll need to find those elsewhere, e.g. on Meta.)

Comment: Plus One, for the _Internet Archive_