# Mandatory tag description when creating new tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation

I propose mandatory tag description when user creates new tag.

We will have following advantages if this feature will be accepted.

1. Understanding if particular tag should be burned or not. Is it useful or useless.
2. Avoiding cases when tag has multiple purposes or featureless.
3. When tag is not relevant. Will help users to understand to use this tag or not.
4. For general erudition. Will give us knowledge about this tag and area of application.

Comment: Given that [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129624/promote-tag-wiki-creation-for-new-tags) is status-declined I highly doubt making it mandatory would gain traction.

Answer (score 5):

This would be complicated.

First, the tag wiki must be able to quickly explain what is on-topic with the tag and what is not. Like with [python](/questions/tagged/python), the tag wiki explains that the tag should only be used when you are using any version of Python (the coding language). That's why all Python questions have this tag or some variation of this tag rather than [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [c](/questions/tagged/c) unless the question includes them too but that's a different story.

Next, the tag summary must elaborate on the tag wiki. With new tags, there will be some experimenting with the tag to see what questions can use it and which cannot. This will probably raise questions in Meta and will require editing or creating a new tag wiki for the tag. Anyways, @rene mentioned:

> Given that [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129624/promote-tag-wiki-creation-for-new-tags) is status-declined I highly doubt making it mandatory would gain traction.

Furthermore, if the user is inexperienced about how to make a proper tag wiki, they might create something a little vague. Take the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag. If this was mandatory and a new user had to make a wiki,  they might enter something super obvious:

> For Python questions

Comment: I think that it will be useful if after creating new tag, user would write 2-3 sentences about it's purpose. Also this "obvisous" description it can solved by minimum length and/or pattern checking. I think tag creation should be responsible action.