# Prevent diamond moderators from accidentally creating hyphenless duplicate tags when asking new questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderators

Earlier today, a diamond moderator created a new question, and also created a new tag to go along with it.

It happens that the tag already existed, only with hyphens.  I've corrected the mistag.

If you're just tuning in, we've historically had a problem with people creating duplicate tags that differ *only* in hyphenation.  The system was modified a while ago to detect such possible duplicates and will force normal users to use the existing tag instead of creating a new one.

Moderators are exempted from this restriction so that existing tags can have their hyphenation changed via synonyms and/or mass retagging.

This exemption should *not* be extended to the new question form, as it seems to be now.  It will be one less way for people to shoot themselves in the foot.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10543583/revisions) if you're curious.

e: [It also happens during editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12411932/revisions), though that *is* working as intended...

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help myself [finding the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10543583/revisions). *I had to know!*

Comment: I don't think we should *prevent* them from doing it, but a pop-up notification would be nice.

Comment: I'm blindly assuming that blocking the hypenation behavior on the new question form will be easier than the `status-planned` [confirmation of all new tag creation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation) feature.

Comment: \*huge, disappointing facepalm\*

Answer (score 12):

Speaking as a moderator on several sites and most active tag curator on another, I would in fact like to go further: I would like to have a confirmation pop-up whenever I create a new tag. I'm sure I've introduced more than one tag on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) due to a typo. If I'm creating a tag, I know I'm creating a tag, and this doesn't happen every day. Asking for confirmation for this unusual action would be warranted.

This should apply to all users, even moderators, but only on graduated sites. On beta sites, creating new tags is far more common and a confirmation pop-up would be a nuisance.

Comment: You'll want to [upvote this feature request then](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation).  It's been status-planned for a year and a half now...

Comment: @Charles [I not only upvoted it a long time ago, I'd even set a bounty.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/62591/revisions) And now another.