# Merge the multidimensional-ish tags

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

There are currently four tags related to multidimensional arrays, lists, hashes, etc.

1. [multidimensional](/questions/tagged/multidimensional)
2. [multi-dimensional](/questions/tagged/multi-dimensional)
3. [multi-dimensional-scaling](/questions/tagged/multi-dimensional-scaling)
4. [multidimensional-array](/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array)

<s>All these tags are related and should be merged into [multidimensional-array](/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array). The [multidimensional-array](/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array) tag has the most questions (3367) and has an excerpt.</s>

Maybe we should merge all these tags into [multidimensional](/questions/tagged/multidimensional)? That way it is clearer that lists, hashes, etc. are included in [multidimensional](/questions/tagged/multidimensional). And as [Some Helpful Commenter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148672/some-helpful-commenter) pointed out, the term multidimensional also applies to databases.

> Multidimensional can refer to [databases](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing#section_1). E.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3687643/672118)

---

### Seriously. Can we get this done?

Comment: Multidemensional can refer to [databases](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing#section_1) . E.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687643/how-do-i-add-dimensions-to-textual-data-in-a-database)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Maybe we should merge them all into [tag:multi-dimensional] then?

Comment: There's a conflict between those that want to see tags collapsed into fewer, more general tags (like you do here), and those who want people to use more specific, less ambiguous tags... The tag wiki for [tag:multidimensional] says *"Please don't use this as a meta-tag. Use [tag:multidimensional-array] or [tag:hash-of-hashes] instead!"*  You'll have to resolve that conflict first, before we do any merging.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So if we just edited the tag wiki, would that resolve the conflict?

Comment: That would certainly paper over it.  But, based on that tag wiki, it seems that one or more people would rather have more specific tags like [multidimensional-array] and [multidimensional-database], instead of the tag combinations of [multidimensional] [array] and [multidimensional] [database].  This wouldn't be the first time such a preference has been stated, either.

Comment: Well I can guarantee you at least five people want all these tags merged into [tag:multidimensional].

Comment: We have [tag:multidimensional] *and* [tag:multi-dimensional]??

Comment: @DonalFellows Si.

Comment: @DonalFellows, such shenanigans are the reason why [non-moderators are no longer able to create tags that differ in spelling only by hyphenation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132225/prevent-diamond-moderators-from-accidentally-creating-hyphenless-duplicate-tags).