# Can't create [git-tf] because [git-tfs] exists

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

**[Git-Tfs](https://git-tfs.com/)** is a Windows OSS project which already benefits from a tag on SO (see [git-tfs](/questions/tagged/git-tfs))

Microsoft recently **[announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/announcing-git-integration-with-tfs/)** the release of a multiplatform tool named **[Git-TF](https://web.archive.org/web/20180108004730/http://gittf.codeplex.com:80/)**.

**Project descriptions:**

- **Git-Tfs:** git-tfs is a two-way bridge between TFS and git, similar to git-svn.
- **Git-TF:** Git-TF is a set of cross-platform, command line tools that facilitate sharing of changes between TFS and Git.

Although those two products are *very* similar, they're completely different from a code perspective and maintained by different teams.

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993228/unable-to-execute-git-tf-command) related to the Microsoft product was recently asked. If was wrongly tagged with the [git-tfs] tag. However, I wasn't allowed to retag it with a new [git-tf](/questions/tagged/git-tf) tag as stated by the error message *"Creating the new tag [git-tf](/questions/tagged/git-tf) is not allowed since the tag [git-tfs](/questions/tagged/git-tfs) already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta"*. I eventually used the [git](/questions/tagged/git) and [tfs](/questions/tagged/tfs) tags.

As I don't think we can do anything to fix Microsoft lack of imagination when it comes to naming product, maybe should we allow the creation of the [git-tf](/questions/tagged/git-tf) tag (with a very explicit wiki description to help with the disambiguation).

Comment: The inability to create the new tag to go along with the question is probably part of a thing currently in place to prevent *accidental* new tag creation.  It probably thinks that 'tfs' is a *plural* and that 'tf' is the singular form.  We had this problem a *lot* in the past.  [Moderators can bypass the filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132225/135887).

Comment: I would try name like **git-tf-tools** instead

Comment: @gnat: I don't feel that **git-tf-tools** is obvious as the tag for `git-tf` -- I don't think this will alleviate significant confusion for the `git-tfs` tag...?

Comment: I don't suppose we can get away with renaming `git-tfs` to `git-team-foundation-server`, can we.  Ah, Microsoft product names...

Comment: @Charles: It's a little wordy to type "git team-foundation-server clone"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tf

Please feel free to provide a detailed tag wiki to guide its usage and disambiguate it from [git-tfs](/questions/tagged/git-tfs).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried to edit the wiki, unfortunately, it looks like I can't input anything (see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Da234.png)). Is this a permission related issue or should I give some time to a background task to finalize the creation of the tag?

Comment: @nulltoken There was a pending edit already in the queue. I approved it. Please review it and see if any other changes are necessary. Thanks!

Comment: The wiki content is great. Thank you @EdwardThomson!