# A new unhyphenated tag can be created when a hyphenated version exists as a synonym

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-creation

This is the goatee-wearing evil twin version of  [new hyphenated tag can be created when an unhyphenated version exists as a synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183356/135887) from this past summer.

Today someone [created](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20503228/revisions) [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp).

[c-sharp](/questions/tagged/c-sharp) exists as a synonym of [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

The tag selection mechanism should automatically have picked [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) for the user after resolving the synonym, but that did not happen.  It should have.

Comment: Stop the bug regression!

Comment: @psubsee2003, normal users can't create tags that differ only in hyphenation, but [moderators can](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132225/135887), just for those rare conditions where you need to work around the hyphenation filter.