# Make tag selection more seamless and less error-prone on Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

This question was posted using the Android App.

When posting questions using the Android application, tag selection can be a little tricky & error-prone.

The web application provides an autocompletion list of suggestions as you type, but no such list appears in the Android app. It would be very useful if similar functionality could be implemented there.

Also it appears that entering a new tag is friction-free, as might happen when fat fingering a tag. As a demonstration I have tagged this question with a false tag.  It should not be this easy to create a new tag, as I would guess the majority of these cases would be mistakes.

Comment: The creation of a new tag has always been [rather unguarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation). Not actually different for Android, though I imagine that on a phone, it'll be even easier to fat-finger. All the more reason summat should be done on this.

Comment: @GraceNote:  Perhaps, but I would argue it should be much more difficult, perhaps even impossible, to create a tag using the android app, since mistakes are so likely.  I have posted two questions using the andoid application app so far, and made mistakes in each.  I was able to correct them both before submitting, but I would guess that as the app gets rolled out in to the wild, many more spurrious tags will get created.

Comment: Now, the app does provide tag suggestions once you start typing.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this done. Boy that feels good. You can start playing with it as of version 0.1.59 coming out later tonight.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Running v0.1.59 and I don't see this interface. Is there some trick to make it work?

Comment: Ooh good catch @StevenV , looks like I messed up a merge and didn't enable it for non-devs, will fix for next release.