# Question-asking layout needs to be rethought

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, android-app

Half the screen estate is already taken up by the keyboard. Could the body section of the question asking screen be popped-out/expanded when focused? I can only see one line of text as I am typing questions (about 40 characters). The page neither scrolls nor expands appropriately, and it's a shame to see a textarea smaller than a textbox.

I believe a picture speaks a thousand words:

[image]

---

Currently the best work-around is rotate the phone to use landscape mode:

[image]

---

Something could be done to make the body textarea fit the top in portrait mode, like this:

[image]

Comment: Also, please [make tag selection more seamless and less error-prone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191412/posting-questions-make-tag-selection-more-seamless-and-less-error-prone)

Comment: Yeah this is a bug. It's not yet working as intended...

Comment: Maybe your screen just isn't big enough :P

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'll like to see a feature where the screen expands to fit the content

Comment: Why is the keyboard so...ugly? Is that just how Android keyboards look? (I have no idea, I'm an iPhone user.)

Comment: @CodyGray custom SwiftKey keyboard, with custom font - you can do anything to customize an Android =)

Comment: -1 for Comic Sans ;)

Comment: @Cole That isn't Comic Sans, it's Choco Cooky

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be have been resolved in a previous update. The body field now automatically stretched with the input and the app-view is scrollable versus the keyboard resizing it to take up a very small portion of the view. Feel free to re-open this with new screenshots if you think it's still a problem.