# UI suggestion for Posting Question page on the Android App

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

I have downloaded the Stack Exchange Android app this morning and loved the way this app is built.

Being Android developer, I must say it's developed using the latest UI Pattern (Navigation drawer) and there way it would be helpful to reduce navigation and provides User friendliness.

But here I would like to suggest a one point which I found missing in Posting Question page.

The whole app is developed using Navigation drawer and Holo UI Pattern but not followed the Holo pattern in Posting Question page. You can check the input box (i.e. EditText) in below snap. This is not an actual Holo EditText.

[image]

**Input box (i.e. EditText) should looks like as depicted in below snap:**

[image]

### Resolution:

I know current app is for beta testing and many are saying that it would waste time and delay the beta launch. But here I would suggest programmer of the app to include the [**HoloEveryWhere**](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) library. There is nothing much to do with this library, just include this in project and there you go!!

### Update:

As one gentlemen has said:

> The UI is lovely, and the layout would look ugly with a full holo
>   theme. Not to mention the UX of holo TextBox elements is terrible
>   because there's no spacing.

I would request him to check Gmail Android app with Holo UI.

[image]

Comment: Please explain *why* we should be using Holo.

Comment: @balpha as such there is not an issue for users using android 1.5 or 4.3 but its a UI difference. Android 4.3 is having cool UI as compared to Android 1.5 :) and I am sure programmer has given background to input box which is not necessary, ***instead we can have plain/Holo UI which makes UI decent and clear.***

Comment: I have my thoughts and reservations around the UI, but I can't see the benefit of using Holo.  Would you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @PareshMayani Ew, why do people think every app has to be identical. The UI is lovely, and the layout would look ugly with a full holo theme. Not to mention the UX of holo TextBox elements is terrible because there's no spacing.

Comment: Let me be clear: The app's design is the way it is. If you suggest we move to Holo (which, by the way, I'm personally not a great fan of), you will have to give a more compelling reason than "it makes UI decent and clear", because I don't think the current design (which, by the way, was created by an actual designer, not by a programmer as you suggest) lacks these qualities. I mean, thanks a lot for alpha testing and giving feedback, but when you request huge changes like this, there have to be *reasons*.

Comment: @Hiroto I don't agree with your point. Please check Gmail android app and the snap given above.

Comment: I agree with @balpha. It's clean, simple and works. It's not like it looks horrible and breaks in every other device. We need better reason to consider this.

Comment: @balpha I would request you to check Gmail and Yahoo Android app. Can you please? The app UI looks decent and consistent from Android 2.1 to Android 4.3

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, or even a user, but I really don't see the difference here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @CodyGray Could you please check and review 2 snaps given above? One is of Stackexchange having background for all the Input box and another is Gmail android app where Googlers has developed app with Native UI and its without any extra effort for preparing background or placing background to the Input box. Still Gmail app is looks decent and consistent in all the versions of Android + the same look in Mobile/Tablet without pixel stretching.

Comment: Have to agree with @balpha, the current UI is crisp, clear and easy to use; and before anyone says it, yes, I have seen the Gmail UI above I use it on my phone and don't see any significant difference to warrant such an overhaul.

Comment: I just checked my GMail App, as @PareshMayani has cited as an example, on my Droid 3 (running Android 2.3.4) and it looks EXACTLY like the current StackExchange app - so I'm not sure how you can claim that GMail "looks consistent from Android 2.1 to Android 4.3" because of Holo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as I like Holo, the current design for the text boxes seems much better - the Holo design gives an indication that the body space is constrained & leaves a lot of empty space below the fields.

In contrast, the current design gives an indication that the body must be something which has to be elaborated, and not constrained

Comment: I think you should suggest to Google that they haven't done cool innovation in new UI!!

Comment: @Paresh not denying it's nice, it's just not very usable - lot of things Google has done with their UI is pretty cool but really isn't usable

Answer (score 3):

I do not agree with this suggestion, as the current layout and design is functional ([with the exception of the body textarea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191471/question-asking-layout-needs-to-be-rethought)). Simply just reverting to the default UI would waste time and delay the beta launch, when we should be focusing on ironing out bugs.

If it would solve the textarea problem, I'm all in for it.

Comment: I don't agree it would waste time and delay beta launch, because programmer just has to include HoloEveryWhere library and it will give the same UI looks in all the versions. And your problem linked above would also get resolved.

Comment: Thanks :) I have included snap of Gmail Android app to make my point even more clear.