# Tag suggestions when asking question?

Tags: support, tags, android-app

[AsheeshR's comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191412/posting-questions-make-tag-selection-more-seamless-and-less-error-prone#comment616025_191412) makes suggests there is some sort of auto completion or suggestion system in place in the Android app when asking questions. I'm running v0.1.25 and I don't see any suggestions if they are indeed implemented. If it isn't implemented, then it seems like there is already a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191412/posting-questions-make-tag-selection-more-seamless-and-less-error-prone) for this to be implemented, so you can mark it as a duplicate.

[image: screenshot of asking question with unfinished tag]

Comment: Not getting any suggestions anymore.

Comment: AsheeshR's suggestions were most likely coming from the built-in spell check on the phone. However, this feature is implemented now so I marked it as a duplicate like you suggested.