# Cannot create [suggestion] tag because of [discussion] tag in Android app

Tags: bug, tags, android-app

I just tried to post a question with [suggestion](/questions/tagged/suggestion) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tags together and it's giving error message as given below:

> [image: error message]
>
> <sup>Error message before MSE/MSO splitting</sup>
>
> You are attempting to create the tag [suggestion]; however the tag [discussion] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on http://meta.stackexchange.com

Are suggestion and personal tags same?

Comment: That doesn't look like a bug to me. Rather a feature. It informs you that creating a [suggestion] tag might not be necessary.

Comment: But message should be somewhat informative and meaningful. This current message is saying that I am trying to create Suggestion but already discussion tag is exist. Is it really meaningful?

Comment: @PareshMayani If it meant the tag `suggestion` already existed, it wouldn't mention the discussion tag. The text reads fine to me.

Comment: Sure that is meaningful @PareshMayani. Depending on the actual question, and you saying that you also tagged it [discussion] already, one could argue that it should be recommending [feature-request] instead, but other than that it seems fine to me.

Comment: Maybe the text should read something like, "You are attempting to create the tag [suggestion]; however the tag [discussion] already exists and could be used instead." If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The confusion was caused by [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag having [suggestions](/questions/tagged/suggestions) tag as its synonym. SE prevents similar tag creation (e.g. singular-plural tag pairs, [suggestion](/questions/tagged/suggestion) vs [suggestions](/questions/tagged/suggestions)), and that's what the error message was trying to convey.

Also, it's [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) on v1.0.84 beta<sup>or [somewhere before that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203901/241919)</sup>. The app doesn't allow free input on tags anymore; user can only search and use  available tags from the list (excluding synonymized tags)

Comment: I am wondering why my questions are getting answered lately! This question was asked 3 years back, even I can't believe :P

Comment: @PareshMayani I was in kind of a crusade to reduce [tag:android-app] [tag:bug] and thus, stumbled upon this question, so... why don't I answer it, if I (more-or-less) know the answer :P

Comment: Yeah I was also wondering why reported bugs by me are still open! But thank you for posting answer and closing down it!