# Show the name of the tag I added, not the synonym it redirects to if I can't add it

Tags: feature-request, bug, tag-synonyms, error-message

Take a look at this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Which tag is the issue? Exactly. It turns out that [re-instalation](/questions/tagged/re-instalation) is a synonym of [installation](/questions/tagged/installation).

Please could the error message read *"The 're-installation' tag is not allowed."*

Comment: +1, good feature request to clarify the confusion like [in this case on Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199164/cannot-create-suggestion-tag-because-of-discussion-tag-in-android-app/277679#277679)