# Confirmation when creating a new tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Today I created [my first tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/daft/info) and I was surprised that **NO** confirmation was required.

I found [this question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62591/215829) suggesting a confirmation on new tag creation, but it dates from 2 years ago and it is in `status-planned`.

This confirmation is very important to avoid mistyped tags, which may become a bigger issue in the future...

Comment: <snark>Tags are supposed to describe the *question*, not [the *user*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daft) !</snark>

Comment: I don't know what you meant by this, but [here is a reference of what kind of daft I am talking about](http://daft-pgm.org/)...

Comment: Yes, it was a joke. I linked to the definition. Daft can mean "silly" or "foolish", perhaps even "insane". I was sure that wasn't what you meant, of course.