# What is a rejected migration?

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions, migration-rejection

I have noticed that in both the 10k tools and in many Meta questions, 'rejected' migrations are referenced. What are they? How is one rejected? What happens?

Comment: I believe its when the question is closed on the site it was migrated to. After that the question goes back to the original site.

Comment: @bluefeet Aaack, thanks. Being able to create new tags is kind of a dangerous thing - I wish it would ask me before just making the tag :)

Comment: @Undo [[status-planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation)]

Comment: @Doorknob ... for two years. One would think it would only take six to eight weeks to implement such a feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [migration-rejection](/questions/tagged/migration-rejection):

> A migration rejection occurs when the target site closes the question for any reason other than **exact duplicate** or **off-topic belong on**. When a rejection occurs, the question is locked on the target site and sent back to the original site, where it is unlocked and remains closed as off-topic.