# "Save Edits" button is never re-enabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits

Whenever I click "Save Edits" when a prerequisite is not met (for instance, not entering a 10-character-long edit summary or not changing anything at all), and then fix whatever is disabling the button, the button always remains disabled.

Sample steps to reproduce:

1. Start editing a question. Change the text of it or something, but don't enter anything in the edit summary field.
2. Click "Save Edits" and watch it get disabled.
3. Type enough in the edit summary box.
4. The button's still disabled!

Comment: On what site? What browser? No repro for me, it's disabled for a second then re-enabled all by itself when the error message appear.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm using Firefox 30.0 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Repro on Firefox 30 and Chrome 35 (main release) on Win 8.1 on SO.

Comment: Happens to me sometimes, but it's not consistently reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [new validation step that was recently added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation/233897#233897) uncovered an old bug here that was previously rare enough to go by unnoticed. I'm deploying the fix as we speak, so this should be back to working correctly in a few minutes. It's a JavaScript fix, so to be precise, it'll work correctly if the page was *opened* after the fix was deployed.