# Don't ask whether to create a new tag if the new tag name is invalid

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-creation, blocked-tags

Stack Exchange ate my edit!

The steps to reproduce are pretty specific.

1. Go to a site where there is a [warning pop-up when you attempt to create a new tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation/233897#233897). This is enabled on some graduated sites, including [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).
2. Visit a question with a pending suggested edit. You have to be on the question page, not in the review queue. You must have the privilege to review the edit (2000 rep in my case, it could presumably work if you were the author) and must not be a moderator.
3. Click “edit(1)” to review the edit inline, then “Improve Edit”.
4. Add a tag to the post which does not exist, and which cannot be created by non-moderators. I tried a plural tag (e.g. `javas` cannot be created because `java` exists) and a blacklisted tag.
5. A pop-up appears, asking “Are you sure you want to create new tags?”. Click “Yes, I'm sure”.
6. The page goes gray (like it normally does when the improved edit is submitted to the server), and nothing else happens.

At step 5, instead of asking about creating a new tag, the server should realize that the user is not allowed to create that tag and directly display the message informing the user that the tag requires moderator intervention or is blacklisted.

When improving an edit from the suggested edit review queue, the bug is also present, but it's only a minor interface nuisance: the user is prompted to confirm the tag creation, then informed that the tag cannot be created and allowed to continue editing. When improving the edit inline from the question page, this bug is bad because the edit is lost.

Cancelling the tag creation confirmation prompt at step 5 also results in a gray screen, with the edit lost.

For SE developers wanting to dig in the server logs, I accidentally triggered this bug on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027940/weak-symbol-attributes-and-extern-declarations), trying to add the tag `weak-symbols` because completion had been a bit slow and I hadn't noticed that `weak-symbol` existed. I then played with [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6273199), using “Improve Edit” with tag-only modifications that I knew would be rejected.