# Should creators of the infamous year tags and dangling version tags have their Taxonomist badge revoked?

Tags: discussion, tags, taxonomist-badge

Now that [year tags and dangling version tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62545/please-help-me-eliminate-year-tags-and-dangling-version-numbers) are gone (cleanup is automatic and effective in 24 hours, right?), remains the matter of the Taxonomist badges for those behind these messes. Should the badges be revoked?

Comment: Let's not start vendettas. They generally end in blood lost on all sides.

Comment: It's not a vendetta. Badges give credit where credit is due, and here credit was not due, yet the badge was given, as a reward for a mistake that got out of hand.

Comment: Yeah, whatever happened to that global tag recalc that Jeff said was on its way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; a lot of people have been awarded the taxonomist badge for creating stupid tags (in fact, the badge itself is stupid and doesn't encourage good behavior, in my opinion; if anything should be removed is the badge for everyone).

If we remove it from those people it will set a bad precedence. What happens next time someone creates a not-very-bad tag that later gets removed? Should they get their badge revoked? If not then it becomes a subjective thing, which will lead to all sort of bad things.

If you propose that the system be changed and revoke all badges (including for example "Great question") when the person doesn't qualify for them anymore then I may agree (but I'm not sure), but creating "special cases" is bad.

If it's any consolation if they create another tag that reaches 50 questions they won't be awarded the badge again, since now they "owe" one to the system.

Overall I just don't think it's a big deal, it's just a silver badge, the average active user has a dozen, what's one more - even if not deserved?

Comment: I like the karmic justice of them not being able to get another (potentially genuine) badge. At the same time, I'm not suggesting a system-wide rule. We have about 10 badges we *know* were awarded for people making a mistake. I think we can agree that in the case layed out above, the tags were not meant to be. If and when a not-very-bad tag gets removed, we should arbitrate on that one alone, and not let this potential situation interfere with the present cases.

Comment: Accepted. I get into OCD overdrive sometimes. Seems overly picky with retrospect.