# Please blacklist the [studio] tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

<strike>For the longest of time</strike> Since August 2010 I've [lamented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62545/please-help-me-eliminate-year-tags-and-dangling-version-numbers) the misuse of tag *stems* and two word tags. I have personally burninated [studio](/questions/tagged/studio) as it was always the stem of another tag, most often [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio), but others too. There are, to my knowledge, no software called just "Studio", nor technology.

I'd like to take it to the next logical step and ask for [studio](/questions/tagged/studio) to be added to the blacklist.