# Please blacklist [visual] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

A long time ago, we had a lot of questions tagged [visual](/questions/tagged/visual) and [studio](/questions/tagged/studio) for [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio). The [suggestion to ban "studio"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115306/please-blacklist-the-studio-tag) did not take, but surprise, getting rid of "visual" was easier and happened.

It's back like an old villain in a cheap sequel, and the misuse in tags is back with it.

Please get rid of [visual](/questions/tagged/visual).

Comment: @nhahtdh The tag wiki got edited today. The tag was created [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22154092/revisions) it seems. There were 4 questions tagged with it. It *will* come back.

Comment: It's on my list of **217** tags I keep dead.  Unfortunately, blacklisting is a dev-only option, and the devs have blacklisted exactly one tag in the past two years.

Comment: Blacklisting is only reserved for egregious cases, like [designer-handbags].