# Long words in comments overlap side bar

Tags: bug, comments, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

Like I said, there was a really long number posted in a comment to an answer [on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504361/what-is-the-number-equivalent-to-1e100/3504399#3504399)  This is now overflowing out of its border thusly:

[image: comments not wrapping]

I am using IE8 running Windows7.

Comment: Awww, but it's still an issue.

Comment: unfixable because the table that comment is in, is variable width, and must stay that way. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a valid use case / business case for 50-to-100-character long strings of non-whitespace in comments.

Not until the day comes when we need to tag things `C++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++`
... at which point I will ditch software and go back to art.