# Comments not getting line broken for some strings

Tags: bug, comments, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

Looks like there's an issue observable on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818107/extract-large-matlab-dataset-subsets) with comments not getting broken up to prevent formatting overflows.

Problem observed in Chrome.