# Why are comments overlapping the sidebar?

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, firefox, unicode

On [one MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137932/147191), the comments are overlapping the related questions sidebar. Is this something to do with the weird formatting of the first comment?

[image: Screenshot]

Browser: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0`

Comment: I see this on Firefox indeed, and not on Chrome. You really want to include browser information in your report, as well as a link to the post.

Comment: The post in question: [Which SE site is best suited for blocking a website on HTTPS (enforcing Safesearch)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137932)

Comment: This is due to the strike preventing work wrap. This is NOT real strike, those are unicode character combined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Two words: time travel....shame on you.

Comment: @Bart: I've erased all evidence it was my wrongdoing. If you have proof I'd love to eras^Wsee it!

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Thanks. Silly of me. Should have included that link to start with.

Comment: Ah, finally, I made it into a screenshot.

Comment: *Why* have I received two votes on this in the past week? People are strange.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, since comments won't allow the ordinary <strike>strike</strike> formatting, someone there tried (and succeeded!) to trick the system by combining Unicode characters resembling English letters with a strike through them.

This results in one long stream of characters without any blank space, no different than:

> `sincecommentswon'tallowtheordinary<strike>strike</strike>formattingsomeonetheretried(andsucceeded!)totrickthesystembycombiningunicodecharacters`

Each browser handles such things in its own way; I don't think there's much to be done.

Just in case, here is the culprit string of characters:

```
P̶o̶s̶s̶i̶b̶l̶y̶ ̶[̶W̶e̶b̶ ̶A̶p̶p̶s̶]̶(̶h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶w̶e̶b̶a̶p̶p̶s̶.̶s̶t̶a̶c̶k̶e̶x̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶)‌​̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶s̶i̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶'̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶s̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶t̶i̶s̶f̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶r̶o̶w̶s̶e̶r̶ ̶p̶l̶u̶g̶i̶n̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶x̶y̶,̶ ̶I̶'̶d̶ ̶s̶a̶y̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶ ̶S̶U̶
```

If you run the above through an [ASCII converter](http://jsfiddle.net/nmtb4/) (this one was built from scratch just now, as I didn't find any decent converter online) you will see there is no blank space but rather a character with ASCII value 822 following each letter.

Comment: Use the Basmala for maximum effect. Works on Firefox 42 Ubuntu 15.10: ﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty common display bug that can be triggered in many ways: [silly Unicode tricks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240022/a-comment-is-breaking-layout), [long code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230161/comment-crashes-way-into-hot-questions), [broken MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/formatting-bug-long-mathjax-or-code-blocks-break-entire-post-or-page), [missing MathJax delimiters](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/rendering-error-comments-with-mathjax-syntax-errors-overflow-their-boxes), [changing the font size in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231232/expanded-comments-impossible-to-read-in-chrome) or [in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192796/show-more-comments-produces-a-layout-overflow-on-firefox), etc.  It was first reported [a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow), and a server-side kluge was added to "fix" it (occasionally breaking [code embedded in comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12340/make-stackoverflow-explode-bookmarklet/12825#comment42566_12825) or [very long URLs](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7195/comment-editor-breaks-some-urls) as a side effect), but it didn't really solve the problem completely.

The common thread in all these bug reports is that they involve some kind of an over-wide unbreakable block of text in a comment, which causes the table that contains the comments to extend to accommodate it, overflowing out of the main content area and into the sidebar.

There's a simple CSS fix that (mostly) solves this bug: just set an explicit `max-width` on the comment text cells:

```css
.comment-body {
    max-width: 628px;
    padding-right: 2px; /* kluge to avoid occasional spurious scroll bars on Chrome */
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This will cause any over-wide comments to stay within their prescribed bounds, breaking long words if necessary, and acquiring a horizontal scroll bar if even that doesn't help, like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

---

[image: Screenshot 2]

<sup>(The `padding-right: 2px` kluge is a workaround for what appears to be [an uncommon Chrome bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240352) causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear even for comments that are not over-wide.  Basically, Chrome's layout algorithm seems to sometimes mis-estimate how wide the table cell should be, and ends up making it one or two pixels too narrow; the extra padding appears to give it enough slack to accommodate such mistakes.)</sup>

**Ps.** This fix is include in the latest version (v1.22) of the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script.  (Earlier versions had a slightly different fix, which used `table-layout: fixed` instead.)  The `word-wrap: break-word` feature will be added in SOUP v1.30.  (It's already present in the v1.29 devel branch.)

Comment: Wow, didn't know this issue has such a long history...