# horizontal scrollbar for comment-container?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, design

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26140091/1803692), I get following completely filled and unscrollable horizontal scrollbar:

[image]

I *guess* it might be due to following css-rule:

> ```
> .comment-body {
>     max-width: 630px;
>     overflow: auto;
>     overflow-y: hidden;
> }
> ```

Because when I manually add `overflow-x: hidden;` with the chrome dev-console, the scrollbar vanishes.

**Additionally** when I actually scroll the scrollbar the following happens (color inversion extension disabled):

[image: asd]

<sub>For reference, I am using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m on Windows 7 with a monitor res of 1680x1050</sub>

Comment: Same browser, same OS, no repro. Why is it dark? Good chance whatever theme you got that makes it dark, also breaks some CSS. Try disabling the theme and see.

Comment: @ShadowWizard disabled the extension, repro remains.

Comment: So some kind of dark magic... hopefully others would be able to repro as well.

Comment: It looks like you're using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), which, as of v1.22, injects the CSS rule you quoted to work around [another bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154788). I'll try to fix it if I can reproduce it. If you find more new bugs, it may be a good idea to check if disabling SOUP fixes them, and, if so, report them directly on [the SOUP page](http://stackapps.com/a/4488) rather than here. In any case, thanks for the report!

Comment: (Alas, I can't reproduce this on my Chromium 37.0.2062.120 / Ubuntu 14.04 (281580), with or without SOUP. I don't have a convenient Windows box at hand to check there; for all I know, it might be font-dependent or something weird like that.)

Comment: (Just tossed a status-deferred on there so the SE devs know this isn't their bug.)

Comment: @Laura Replacing that with status-norepro since, well, it's not our bug. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to "kill" the bug by disabling SOUP, for now I dropped a comment at the [SOUP Page on stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch/4488)

As of now, this is officially acknowledged as a bug in the [list of known bugs.](https://stackapps.com/a/4488/28738) Additionally Ilmari has already incorporated a fix into the development branch ;)

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce this. :( Anyway, since it's apparently reproducible for you, would you mind testing a few things for me? 1) What is the actual width of the `div.comment-body` element, and of the `span.comment-copy` inside it, as shown when you hover the mouse over the tags in the "Elements" tab in developer tools? 2) Does changing the CSS `max-width` to `629px` or `631px` in developer tools change anything? 3) What about adding `width: 630px` to the CSS? Thanks!

Comment: 1) `div.comment-body: 620px`, `span.comment-copy: 621px`. 2) neither changes anything 3) `div.comment-body` now has 630px width, no more scrollbar.  `span.comment-copy` now has 624px width;

Comment: Huh, that's... interesting.  What about setting `width: 620px`, or both that and `max-width: 620px`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen no effect. neither with setting width only  nor with setting both....

Comment: Hmm, what about adding `padding-right: 2px`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that works a charm. div.comment-body is now 620px wide and span.comment-copy 606px. Scrollbar is not there anymore. Thanks for reminding my why I don't like css ;)

Comment: Honestly, I think this is a Chrome bug; there's no good reason why the `span.comment-copy` *should* ever be wider than the `div.comment.body` element, as long as it doesn't exceed the maximum width.  Anyway, I've added the `padding-right` kluge to the SOUP devel branch, and it'll be included in the SOUP v1.24 release (which I plan on making sometime this week).