# The comment section gets partially overlapped on downvoted and accepted answers

Tags: bug, comments, design

The below image shows what I am talking about ([question direct link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36831/238126))

[image: This shows the comments running off the end.]

Comment: It looks fine here. What OS and browser version are you using?

Comment: I see it - Win7, Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m.  Also repoed on IE 11.  With normal zoom level

Comment: TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS_______________SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

Comment: Yeah, that's spam.  Delete the above comment if necessary... it's just an example

Answer (score 1):

If you type way too many characters into the comment box, some of the text will overflow and thus being the example you linked above. The maximum amount of characters that can be typed until the text overflows is unknown to me...

But anyways, comments like that should be flagged as not constructive or too chatty as it is excessively long for no apparent reason. So either someone should fix the code to allow better formatting or just lower the limit of characters you are allowed to type in as a comment. 600 characters seem a little too much for a comment.