# Comments disappearing under advert

Tags: bug, comments, advertising, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

On a recent question I noticed that the comment box disappeared behind the advert

[Add Reference in Framework 4 Application is not showing assemblies in GAC registered with GACUtil V 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616617/add-reference-in-framework-4-application-is-not-showing-assemblies-in-gac-registe/4616676#4616676)

I am using Google Chrome.

I didn't see this problem when I opened the question in IE.

Comment: @JJnguy Not entirely - other browsers seem to break at `/` s, but Chrome doesn't appear to. Somewhat surprising, but I'm not sure if the specs defined which characters to line break on.

Comment: @YiJang, well it is super closely related to the same bug.

Comment: I wouldn't close this as dupe guys. The Post Overflow bug is fixed with Chrome. This one is not.

Comment: @Ladybug If you read Jeff's answer, he says that comments overflowing (not posts) are [status-bydesign]. The fix was for posts (questions and answers), not comments.