# Is there a CSS problem on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

I was looking at [an old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696222/jquery-validator-check-input-against-a-list-of-accepted-values) and when I expand the comments they spread way over everything on the right. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

I see it in Firefox 4.01, Chrome 11.0.696.68, and Opera 11.10 (on Mac).

Comment: What browser? It looks fine on IE8.

Comment: Certainly looks like a problem, I see it too (Firefox 3.6, Mac)

Comment: @Renesis , @mmyers am I posting this to the right place ?

Comment: This is a know bug.  Jeff has stated many times that it is difficult to limit the width of comments because they have variable width.

Comment: @jjnguy  but it wraps just fine until i open the additional comments

Comment: @mcg, that's because the comment that is causing the problem is hidden until you expand them.

Comment: @jjnguy right but that shouldn't matter see my answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yay! More unicode fun!

So far we were inserting soft-hyphens `&shy;` into long comment lines without whitespace to force line-breaks; but it seems that not all browsers can be convinced to make this work in all cases.

We can't use the zero-width space `&#8203;` because it doesn't work in IE; we can't use the zero-width non-joiner `&zwnj;` because that doesn't work in all browser as well.

But alas: It seems the using *both* actually works everywhere. So, from now on, our *Stack Exchange™ WhiteSpace EnforcementOfficer™* is

```
&zwnj;&#8203;
```

Next build, as usual.

Comment: ok I'm sure this is good logic to this but why not use what I suggested..please keep in mind that I am not a css expert

Comment: @mcgrailm See [Jeff's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow/42662#42662) as to why CSS changes don't help in comments.

Comment: still don't get it, seems the answer is because hes not willing to make it fixed with or max-width seems like it's not a good reason but its not my site LOL

Comment: Did you consult with badp or are you putting him out of business? (;

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: He's the Deputy. Which is good for him, because [the Deputy is still alive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXmhyc_QynE).

Comment: Favoriting this answer for my own use in the future.  Also, such a good answer maybe this should be migrated to SO; then again, it's probably a duplicate there :)

Comment: I guess you'll see it one day, but just in case you would not: [what about inserting `<span style="display: inline-block"></span>` instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert/171065#171065)?

Comment: Instead of the often proposed `word-wrap: break-word`, there's also `word-break: break-all`, which works nicely in all my browsers, but  [apparently not in Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-break)... :-(

Comment: (@NickC, late response: if that future has come for you already, then maybe some other non-Unicode trickery is better, if your visitors are copying text. See my comments above. And of course all trickery might make it hard for search engines to index correctly.)

Comment: These characters are now inserted into comments [*even when there's enough whitespace*](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/copy-to-and-from-comment).  Is this normal or is it a bug?

Comment: @Szabolcs Marco is working on that code right now, I've pinged him.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be fixed with

```
.comment-text{
    max-width:50px;
}
```

no ?

**edit**

[image: example image]

it doesn't look like overflow is hidden here

Comment: So, you propose `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: @jjnguy  see edit

Comment: why the down vote ? is this not a logical answer ?

Comment: dunno, it wasn't from me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<wbr>` tags instead of Unicode characters for breakpoints is likely to play better with copy-and-paste in current browsers (especially Firefox).