# Why doesn't [se] always get replaced?

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, magic-links

If you place the `[se]` magic link in a certain position, why doesn't it resolve to [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)?

Make a comment:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[se]aa[se]

And it shows:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)aa[se]

Note the one `[se]` that wasn't replaced.

See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152869#comment506397_3122) for a few more positions where this happens.

Comment: How on earth did you find this out?

Comment: I just saw the comment and figured the guy filled it with `[se]` but some didn't resolve.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[se]aa[se] <- see, one gets resolved, one doesn't.

Comment: @animuson Let's see and `check[se]to[se]` -> check[se]to[se]

Comment: If anything, the bug here is that this text *shouldn't* get replaced unless surrounded by spaces. Replacing things in the middle of words is just silly.

Comment: Well, the bug is really the inconsistent behaviour. I don't really mind which one gets fixed.

Comment: [se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se]

Comment: Hmm. So it doesn't always work :( ([Code source](http://ideone.com/oyHqx2))

Comment: That's a really long comment...

Comment: Looks like an as-SE-rtion failure.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[se]aa[se]

Answer (score 6):

That's because the [whitespace enforcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91512/115866) gets into the way, and frankly – I don't care. A magic link that appears inthemiddleofaridiculouslylongword[se]likethiswherenobodywouldeveractuallyputit is not a realworld use case. If anything, we could just not expand magic links at all if they don't appear as their own words. Outside of the context of sandbox test, a comment like this would be considered abusive anyway.