# Comment spread all over the webpage — unable to edit, unable to delete

Tags: support, bug, comments, mathjax

I wrote a comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869322/can-this-function-be-a-new-test-for-primality) on math-stack-exchange.

The browser (both Chrome and Firefox) didn't take it very well, and spread it all over the webpage, such that both the 'edit' option and the 'delete' option are shadowed (unavailable):

> [image]

How can I resolve this?

P.S.:

I kept adding comments, hoping I could get it fixed and then delete the previous ones.

I realized that the 'delete' option was unavailable only after repeating this several times.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That does seem like a bug - the display is what happens if you add invalid MathJax code in a comment, but the formula is correct. Funnily enough, though, if you (1) copy the formula into the answer box and then (2) add dollar signs, for some reason it shows an error. If you change the last `\rfloor` to, say, `)`, and then back, then it works. If you copy-paste with the dollar signs included it also works. There's some funky edge case getting called there. In any case, you've posted it as an answer so you can just delete your comments (or flag for deletion if you can't).

Comment: @E.P.: Thanks, posted it there instead ([here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23698/131263)). Will delete this one shortly I guess.

Comment: @E.P.: BTW, I'm pretty sure that the LaTex formula was valid at some point (in the last few comments). It's just that when using a long formula in the comment section, one must add a few sporadic spaces here and there (the browser doesn't take it very well as soon as there are too many consecutive non-space characters).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what's going on, I'll post on meta.math when I've got it nailed down. Long story short is that somehow a non-displaying unicode space snuck into your last `\rfloor`. Delete it and re-type it and it should work fine.

Comment: @E.P.: I am aware of the problem that long LaTex formulas with no space characters aren't handled very well when posted in the comment section. I am merely trying to resolve the case at hand, where I am unable to edit or delete those comments due to the mess on my screen.

Comment: See my answer on meta.math and Asaf's comments there. Your browser should have an Inspect Element option upon right click which you should be able to use to hide the banners that are currently blocking the edit and delete buttons. If that doesn't work, flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @E.P.: Thanks. I got as far as 'Inspect Element'. Can't see how to hide an element at this point.

Comment: The procedure depends completely on what browser and system you're using. In Chrome, hovering over the html tags in the Elements tab of the dev tools shows you what you're selecting on the page. To hide an element, right-click the tag and select Hide Element. In other browsers - no idea.

Comment: @E.P.: Thank you, I'm on Firefox (will have to login with Chrome).

Comment: In Firefox you can use Delete Node, if you get the `<div id="sidebar">` it should work.

Comment: A related post: [MathJax in Comment Gets Corrupted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238862).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until this is fixed, you can delete those comments by opening your browser's Console (typically F12) then typing these lines of code, one at a time, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>: (as it's rate limited)

```
$.post("/posts/comments/3829630/vote/10", {"fkey": $("#fkey").val()});
$.post("/posts/comments/3829648/vote/10", {"fkey": $("#fkey").val()});
$.post("/posts/comments/3829649/vote/10", {"fkey": $("#fkey").val()});
```

**Note: you will not get any confirmation dialog, the comments will be deleted instantly**.

To delete further comments this way, all you need is their ID which can be retrieved from the permalink. (the comment's timestamp is a permalink, e.g. `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869322/can-this-function-be-a-new-test-for-primality#comment3829630_1869322` and the ID is 3829630)

In case the timestamp itself is hidden, the comments are also available in [your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments), the title of each comment is the permalink with the comment ID.

Comment: Thanks. Typing these lines of code... where? (There doesn't seem to be any edit-box for that purpose).

Comment: @barakmanos what browser are you using? If Chrome, press F12 in the keyboard, then go to Console tab and type it in there.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos in Firefox it's CTRL+SHIFT+I

Answer (score 1):

Several ways how to get to the delete/edit button are suggested in the posts on Mathematics Meta on this topic, see: [My comments got stretched across the screen, and it won't allow me to edit or delete the comment either.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24987)

To me, the simplest way seem to be changing the Math Renderer. (You can do this in the MathJax menu which you get after right click on a rendered formula. [This post](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/667#669) has a screenshot showing the menu.

You can try various renderers to see which allow you shorter comment. If nothing else, choosing Plain Source as Math Renderer should help with this. (And after fixing the comment you switch this back the the one you prefer.)