# Unparseable link in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, hyperlinks

The possible duplicate link in [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()Ljava/util/Set;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969100/deploying-servlets-in-jboss) is broken.

For future reference, the   [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()Ljava/util/Set;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969497/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-geteffectivesessiont)  link is been parsed as follows:

[image]

It's likely caused by a combination of the parentheses and slashes in the link description. I tried to reproduce it in [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). I got it to work only if I put a space after the `()` in the link description or removed the
slashes from the `java/util/Set` part.

Comment: Yep something here is quirky - good catch!

Comment: [aa.bb.cc: dd.ee.ff()gg/hh/ii;](http://google.com)

Comment: However, the above one works fine. I can't consistently reproduce this.

Comment: Test [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jservlet.ServletContext.getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()Ljava/util/Set;](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120021/unparseable-link-in-comments)

Comment: The "force space to prevent comment overflow" breaks this. I blame Java.

Comment: @balpha: are comment links parsed in client side or what?

Comment: Uhm... no. Why?

Comment: @balpha: you seem to imply/confirm that it works when the longest word of the link description is shorter or contains a(nother) space.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42662/115866