# Putting things in <kbd> tags allows one to get outside the question border

Tags: bug, markdown, images, kbd

## Here is an example (2 image / 2 kbd):

<kbd>[image]</kbd><kbd>[image]</kbd>

## Here is another example (2 images / 1 kbd):

<kbd>[image][image]</kbd>

## Here is yet another example (A lot of stars in a kbd):

<kbd>**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************</kbd>

Comment: Woah... +1 for totally breaking the site. Looks like we need an `overflow: hidden;` somewhere.

Comment: The images behave fine on the mobile site but the *** do not

Comment: This [isn't new](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114743/166294)

Comment: @AlexCoplan: It's actually older than that, but somehow decided to remove my questions on this bug. The same happens with a lot of ` > ` characters on one line... :)

Comment: SE will just get rid of the KBD tag support before fixing this bug, lol.

Answer (score 8):

Here’s a better solution:

```
pre, code, kbd, var, samp {
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

It will make code spans and similar elements automatically wrap to the next line when needed, in all browsers.

Here’s a jsFiddle demonstrating this snippet for an inline `<code>` span: http://jsfiddle.net/VT6Uu/

This should also fix the `>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>` problem in comments.

Yo dawg, here are some quotes within quotes:

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > test

This can be fixed by setting the `blockquote` padding to zero when it’s wrapped in too many `blockquote` elements:

```
blockquote blockquote blockquote blockquote {
  padding: 0;
}
```

In this case, you would be able to visually nest up to three quotes.

To quickly test the above snippets on this page, enter this in your console:

```
$('<style>pre,code,kbd,var,samp{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word}blockquote blockquote blockquote blockquote{padding:0}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

Comment: +1 But doesn't work for comments. Also doesn't work many nested quotes in a post. Perhaps you need to add a selector for the comment and for the blockquote?

Comment: @TomWijsman Added a fix for the nested quotes problem.

Comment: @MathiasBynens For comments, you can apply `word-wrap` to the `<div>` wrapping the comment. See my suggestion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131533/172108

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I have researched a possible solution using CSS:

```
.post-text p {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That completely solves this issue (and any other "it overflows the post" problems).

Comment: type `$('.post-text p').css({overflow:'hidden'});` in console to test :)

Comment: Or `javascript:$('.post-text p').css({overflow:'hidden'});` in the address bar. :)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: What about the `>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>` bug in comments/posts?

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Whats the bug exactly (in comments)?