# Comments are still overflowing

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Jeff tagged [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow) as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and said:

> because we loop through comments on the fly for rendering anyway, we are now force-inserting a soft hyphen boring unicode spaces every so many characters without a space. **So this should be truly fixed now.**

But it doesn't look that way from here:

[image]

(Chrome 18/IE8/FF 9 on Windows 7)

---

To reproduce this, you need a comment with a large number of apostrophes. If you insist on trying it out, you'll of course **use the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)** for that.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Comment: This is a comment containing some actual text. This should wrap correctly and not cause any problems, but I can insert comments that break everything. Just wait.

Comment: Odd; I've tested before and then only found issues [in Firefox](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2399/comments-are-not-wrapped-continued-on-other-side-of-page). Today, this very question shows that things have changed, in either SE or in Chrome? (My Chrome [failed me too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JIoWm.png) with the original troublesome comment that has meanwhile been changed. But I did not validate if the soft-hyphens are actually there.)

Comment: I deleted that BS. Problem is known, so might as well not break the page, hmm?

Comment: @Arjan It's because of my comment containing all the apostrophes. That was breaking everything, but balpha deleted it.

Comment: Overexpands the mobile version. Makes it fat.

Comment: @minitechη You need 500 apostrophes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, you intentionally try and break the page rendering by inserting useless strings of nonsense text in the comments, and then complain when your attempts succeed?

[image: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. Then don't do it.]

Comment: Perfect response. +1

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if software didn't let you intentionally break things?

Comment: Not really, @Null. Then we couldn't have any fun. There will always be more ways to break things if you go looking for them than there are fixes. And as usual, it's a case of intelligently allocating limited resources.

Comment: Precisely; especially since there is no valid use case for any comment that tricks the auto-whitespace insertion (there are just a few cases where that's happening). If a user insists on posting a comment containing 500 apostrophes, that might as well break the page to make us notice that there's a misbehaving user here.

Comment: Problem is more that there's no valid use case for this, but I agree with the general sentiment

Comment: @Ben /me goes and invents,a new language, based on Whitespace architecture. /me calls it Apostrophe. /me uses it in comments on questions pertaining to the language There's your use case ;-).

Comment: @Manishearth Already addressed elsewhere on Meta: lengthy code snippets don't belong in comments. :-)

Comment: For the record: I intend to fix this, I'm just not excited enough to consider it high priority.

Comment: @balpha until you fix it, Woodstock won't be able to use this site. Please think of the birds.

Comment: @BenBrocka: `''' '''''' '' '' '' '''' '''''' ' '` (`Thank you` in Woodstock-ese) Anyway, Woodstock uses spaces as well (IIRC). =P

Answer (score 1):

The boring unicode spaces weren't inserted at places within the string that contained special characters, i.e. characters that either have a special meaning in MarkdownMini, or those that get HTML-encoded. Since your comment solely consisted of characters in the second group, nothing was inserted. This is fixed in the next build.

[Cody's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128444/115866) is still valid, though.