# stack HTML BROKEN in gis stackexchange

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments are still overflowing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128443/comments-are-still-overflowing)

I posted a [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25674/other-base-maps-appearing-pink-when-added-with-osm#comment34707_25674) on the [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25674/other-base-maps-appearing-pink-when-added-with-osm) and the container was not able to hold the text which comprised of the url. It looks like the HTML is broken.

[image]

Comment: Might want to take a screenshot and mention your browser. Looks fine to me.

Comment: Broken for me on Chrome.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Broken for me in Chrome as well.

Comment: Yes this is the same look I am getting

Comment: ok since you have closed it can you tell me the link where the solution is??

Comment: FYI anyone trying to reproduce, I've added two spaces into the comment to stop it from overflowing.

Comment: @Sam007 Check the duplicate.

Comment: Yup that fixed it thanks @balpha. Yannis oh i did not see the link above, thanks and the solution is hillarious