# Strange comment text covers up top tabs on SE android app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

On the [Android app sandbox post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196425/176492), one of the comments (I can't tell what the composition is) covers up the top tabs until they are redrawn. A screenshot is below.
[image]

Comment: Hehehe, all part of my diabolical scheme.... But seriously, I only didn't post this myself because SE's position on weird Unicode has always seemed to be "Yeah, maybe we'll get to that. Someday." I agree with them, it's not really something to worry about. If it hurts when you do that - [don't do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128443/comments-are-still-overflowing/128444#comment350518_128444)

Comment: That's just Zalgo.  Don't worry about it.  Or look dir͢e҉c̢t͢l̴y ą̷̵̙̩t̵̠̰ͅ i͛͐͆͛͌̓ͧ̆ͫ̍̉ͩͫͪ̓̈͆͛҉̧̝̣͔ͅt͌̌̐̓̑ͪͣ̂͐͛ͭ̔̚͡͏̡̗̻̼͓́͜.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Q&A page renewal on v1.0.50 (removing Q&A tabs, making it into single thread), as of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: the rendered content is limited to the container (e.g. post, comment) size.

[image: zalgo doesn't overflow]