# Large amounts of white-space in code cause comments to overflow in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, firefox

Please look at the image.

The right column's text jumbles with some comment text when the comment contains a large amount of white-space inside an inline code block. I guess that's not the design may be the comments should be a little bit more restricted from expanding? What do you think?

> [image]

Now even kinda worse:

> [image]

Comment: This is the lINK:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732371/how-to-add-textfield-in-a-button-when-that-button-is-clicked/22732515?noredirect=1#comment34646946_22732515

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128443/comments-are-still-overflowing http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128888/firefox-comment-formatting-layout-bug-comments-overwritten-by-side-bar-adve

Comment: Looks like a Firefox-only side-affect again [related to this change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one/222376#222376). I've just deleted the comments.

Comment: @animuson: And that's a CSS change affecting newlines in comments adding **extra** breaks. If we see this overflow behaviour in current FF than there is a **different** bug, one that doesn't properly wrap the comments (fewer newlines).

Comment: @Martijn Yeah, it looks like there's just a crap-ton of white-space after each line in that particular comment. They should probably reconsider that change...

Comment: @WhoEverDeletedTheComments: So, will you be deleting all Cooments with CODES in the PAST and FUTURE???... Or instead of Deleting, why NOT UnBug the Bug?

Comment: @Universal We generally delete comments with that much code in them anyways. They're noisy and ugly and don't belong in the comments.

Comment: @animuson Sure sounds fare.... just wondering how will the 100BILLION Registered Members know that their comments are prone to deletion. As a developper, I'd go for a Fix for the Bug and a Making of the ugly CODES look Great.... and Please let me have some UpVotes on this for myReps.... thx

Comment: @Universal Yes, it should be fixed, but that has nothing to do with whether the comments should be deleted or not.

Comment: @UniversalGrasp we have to assume some members visit and read the [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: @animuson Ok, I agree... thx

Comment: @glorfindel I can no longer reproduce this issue in firefox. So I think it would be best to let this post die, maybe even close it as no longer reproducable if others can't repro either. And let the other post live on as the chrome bug.

Comment: @Luuklag hmm ... that makes sense. I can't repro it either. I'll rollback and retract the close vote.

Comment: It was reproduced at the time it was reported as the tag indicates. it should not be closed but rather changed to [tag:status-completed].